# pandas rolling calculation - adding percentage change

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, percentage

I'm trying to convert a pandas Series from percentage change back to levels. The first value in the Series is a number in levels, but all the following values in the Series are percentage changes.
This is my dataframe:

```
+--------+
|  pct   |
+--------+
| 103300 |
|    .06 |
|    .11 |
|    .02 |
+--------+
```

The resulting Series would look like this:

```
+----------+
|  levels  |
+----------+
|   103300 |
|   109498 |
| 121542.8 |
| 123973.6 |
+----------+
```

> 109498 = .06 * 103300 + 103300
>
> 121542.8 = .11 * 109498 + 109498

Each iteration is using the previous newly calculated number. How would I do this in pandas? I've looked at rolling and expanding but I can't get quite what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I'd add `1` to all the percentages:

```
df['levels'] = df.pct
df.levels.loc[1:] += 1

df

         pct     levels
0  103300.00  103300.00
1       0.06       1.06
2       0.11       1.11
3       0.02       1.02
```

...because then it's a matter of simply applying `cumprod()`:

```
df.levels = df.levels.cumprod()

df

         pct       levels
0  103300.00  103300.0000
1       0.06  109498.0000
2       0.11  121542.7800
3       0.02  123973.6356
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the cumulative product feature:

```
df.ix[1:] = df[0] * (df.ix[1:] + 1).cumprod()
#0    103300.0000
#1    109498.0000
#2    121542.7800
#3    123973.6356
```